# Backing out data from an MD5 checksum

Tags: algorithm, hash, md5

Imagine you have an MD5 sum that was calculated from an array of *N* 64-byte elements. I want to replace an element at an arbitrary index in the source array with a new element. Then, instead of recalculating the MD5 sum by re-running it through an MD5 function, I would like to "subtract" the old element from the result and "add" the new piece of data to it.

To be a bit more clear, here's some pseudo-Scala:

```
class Block {
  var summary: MD5Result

  // The key reason behind this question is that the elements might not be
  // loaded. With a large array, it can get expensive to load everything just to
  // update a single thing.
  var data: Array[Option[Element]]

  def replaceElement(block: Block, index: Integer, newElement: Element) = {
    // we can know the element that we're replacing
    val oldElement = block.data(index) match {
        case Some(x) => x
        case None    => loadData(index) // <- this is expensive
      }

    // update the MD5 using this magic function
    summary = replaceMD5(summary, index, oldElement, newElement)
  }
}
```

Is `replaceMD5` implementable? While all signs point to "this is breaking a (weak) cryptographic hash," the actual MD5 algorithm seems to support doing this (but I might be missing something obvious).

Comment: TTBOMK MD5 computation processes bytes strictly in increasing order. If so, you could record the sequence of intermediate (state) values of the MD5 computation after each 64-byte unit: then if data[i] is changed, you could restart the MD5 computation from this point, i.e. recalculate just the remaining (n-i+1)*64 bytes.  If changes are uniformly at random this will save on average half the computation.  TTBOMK any change will alter all "downstream" states in an unpredictable way, so I doubt anything can be done to mitigate near-the-start changes.

Comment: I believe that this is not possible without spending more time then just rerunning md5. Can you please tell why do you believe that **the actual MD5 algorithm seems to support doing this**?

Comment: The issue isn't the computation time of re-running the algorithm -- it's that I have to perform an expensive operation (IOs) to figure out what data to even feed the algorithm.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: Obviously MD5 was not designed with this sort of crazy operation in mind. I don't have an explicit reason to believe this is possible, but it *seems* like it should be, if it is computationally expensive. If it's not possible, then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I better understand what you want to do now.  My solution below assumes nothing about MD5 computation, but involves a tradeoff between IO and storing a large number of MD5 hashes.  Instead of computing the simple MD5 hash of the entire dataset, it computes a different MD5 hash that nevertheless should have the same important property: that any change to any element (drastically) changes it.

1. At the outset, decide on a block size b such that

   - you can afford to read b values from disk (or whatever IO you're talking about) *per change of element*, and
   - you can afford to keep 2n/b MD5 hashes in memory.
2. Create a binary tree of MD5 hashes.  Each leaf in this tree will be the MD5 hash of a size-b block.  Each internal node is the MD5 hash of its two children.  We will use the hash of the root of this tree as "the" MD5 hash.
3. When element i changes, read in the b elements in block RoundDown(i/b), compute the new MD5 hash for this, and then propagate the changes up the tree (this will take at most log2(n) steps).

Comment: While I love your answer, this is the *exact* thing I'm trying to get out of doing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree).

Comment: While I love your comment, it would have *really helped* to make clear that you already tried/thought of this idea and dismissed it (incidentally: why?).

Comment: Fair point. The short answer is that it would be significantly easier from a use perspective to not have to deal with tracking all the internal nodes of this tree (the lowest level of blocks is expressed in trillions, so even with a large branching factor, there's no way to store the internal nodes in memory). I would prefer to not use MD5 at all here (and use a summary system that allows the operation I want), but there are some external factors forcing me to do that as well. I was really hoping there would be some magic math I could use to solve the whole world :-)

Comment: With trillions of leaves, I suppose the block size needed to fit the tree in memory will be enormous :(  I would ask whether the hash needs to be up-to-date *at all times*, or whether it actually suffices to bring it up to date periodically -- if the latter suffices, then you can sort updates by index, batch together all updates that a affect a single block, and get a lot more bang for your load-a-block buck.

Comment: Yup -- that's basically where I'm at. Unfortunately, you're always making a trade off in block size here. The bigger the block, the more batching you get, but the more expensive it is to reload. I think the amount of data I have to deal with puts it in the category of "difficult problems requiring significant engineering time."